# Displaying KML data with user selection?

Tags: postgis, leaflet, openlayers, kml

I want to web map some historical cyclones data which are now in KML files, file/year. So I want the user to select a year from a button and the KML files will be displayed on interactive map).

I started with openlayers and leaflet libraries but as I am beginner in JS as first impression it seems a bit complected to manage different events.

What is the best way to represent these data and what the different components I need?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Leaflet is certainly a good option, out of the box leaflet does not support kml but if you add a plugin like [omnivore](https://github.com/mapbox/leaflet-omnivore) you should be able to get things work reasonably simply.
Perhaps have a shot and post your code to jsfiddle if you get stuck then someone can provide more assistance.

Comment: what about the data, do I need to setup a Geoserver? I want the user to select the desired year of cyclone from a drop-down menu and the track will be displayed on the map.

Comment: No  you do not need Geoserver if you are just wanting to display data from a bunch of kml files. Depening on what you are trying to build Geoserver might be a more long lasting scalable solution but if you're just playing around then kml's should be fine

Comment: I have hundreds of kml files/year! I want the user to select a date (year) and the corresponding kml will be displayed. I don't know what is the structure to retrieve my data by selecting from a drop-down menu.

Comment: In that case you'd be better off working out how to transfer that kml data into something like postgis. You could do that using ogr2ogr http://www.gdal.org/ogr2ogr.html . Once its in postgis you're able to serve it out much more effectively than individual files.